# iAdBannerView not shown in my xcode tools

Tags: ios, xcode, iad

I am trying to add an iAd BannerView to my storyboard. However, I can not find it as one of the items that in my object library.

I added iAd framework from Build phases and though it is not there.

I am running Xcode version 9.2

Comment: Seems to be Deprecated: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iad/adbannerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [their site](https://developer.apple.com/support/iad/), Apple shut down the iAd Network on December 31, 2016. As such, you won't be able to use any of the associated frameworks or symbols therein. You'll have to use a different ad network to put ads in your app

Comment: Yes. The network stopped accepting new members on June 30, 2016. It's gone for good